# C# partial class

Tags: c#, .net, partial-classes

How do I program a partial class in C# in multiple files and in different namespaces?

Comment: Anyone else find it amusing that a user named "Partial" is asking about partial classes?

Comment: Why would you want to be able to do this? What problem have you encounter that you think such a feature would help you solve?

Comment: It's really just a coincidence. I have been on stackoverflow for a couple of weeks.

Comment: @Jason: I just wanted to know how I could spit my code in multiple files. I am rather new to C# (from a C++ background).

Comment: It's the "different namespaces" part that I'm questioning.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't.  From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(VS.80).aspx) ...

> Using the partial keyword indicates
>   that other parts of the class, struct,
>   or interface can be defined within the
>   namespace

Must be in the same namespace.

Per comment:  Here's [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx) that discusses defining a namespace cross multiple assemblies.  From there ...

> Strictly speaking, assemblies
>   and namespaces are orthogonal. That
>   is, you can declare members of a
>   single namespace across multiple
>   assemblies, or declare multiple
>   namespaces in a single assembly.

Comment: Can you have the same namespace over multiple files?

Comment: Yes you can ... over multiple .cs files in the same assembly and over multiple assemblies as well.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot have a partial class in multiple namespaces.  Classes of the same name in different [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k(VS.80).aspx) are by definition *different classes*.

Answer (score 4):

A partial class (as any other class) needs to live in one single namespace (otherwise its another class).

To split it between different files just use the partial keyword after the access keyword:

```
// this bit of the class in a file
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}

//this bit in another file
public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. A partial class means just that: A single class broken into several files. That also means that all files that this partial class consists of must have the same namespace. Otherwise it wouldn't be the same class anymore.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is correct, especially the "Otherwise it wouldn't be the same class anymore" bit.